# can I upgrade/make app for ios7 using xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have an existing app that need to be made compatible to ios7. I am new to ios app development. I have following things:
1. Macbook with MAC OS 10.6.8
2. X code - 4.2

is it possible to recompile the existing app using above to make it compatible for ios7? 
(I know i need atleast MAC OS 10.8 for xcode5)
A little detailed explanation is highly appreciable as I am still figuring out how it works.

If not what all I would need to achieve same? If yes, how?

Comment: iOS7 developemnt only available with xcode5 and xcode5 is support minimum os version is MAC OS10.8  so first off all you have to upgrade os then xcode also then you can do your task.

Answer (score 2):

Its must to have xcode 5 or 5.1 to make app ios7 compatible.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Answer (score 2):

Nope. iOS7 requires Xcode 5+ which requires mavericks. You can upgrade for free to mavericks and get Xcode.
Just open the App Store and upgrade to mavericks (5.3 GB) and then get Xcode 5.1

Answer (score 1):

iOS7 developemnt only available with xcode5 and xcode5 is support minimum os version is MAC OS10.8 so first off all you have to upgrade os then xcode also then you can do your task.

Answer (score 1):

From 1st Feb every app must be build in Xcode 5 and above as per apple declaration

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your existing app, but iOS 7 can run iOS 6 app, it shouldn't be an issue to just let your old app runs.

Of course, you will have to have xCode 5 in order to run and debug on iOS 7 device and simulator.